# timeout exception in asp.net application

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

I cannot figure out why I am getting timeout exception in asp.net application upon signing into application **and** when I restart my webserver I don't get timeout exception?

**Environment:**

Asp.net application(IIS webserver) and DB (Sql server)
both IIS and Sql server are on two different machines.

Sql server timeout:600 seconds

**Webconfig setting:**

```
<httpRuntime maxRequestLength="16384" executionTimeout="270"/>

<sessionState mode="InProc" cookieless="false" timeout="60" stateConnectionString="">
```

Thanks in advance.

**Screenshot of error**:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to add connection timeout in connection string as "Data Source=SQLSERVER;Initial Catalog=MYCATALOG;Integrated Security=True;Connection Timeout=1000".if again "The wait operation timed out" then it is likely you have a database call that took longer than expected. This could be due to any number of things:

- Transient network problem
- High SQL server load
- Problem with SAN, RAID, or storage device
- Deadlock or other form of multiprocess contention

You haven't shared enough information to troubleshoot. The way I would manage this would be to check for other occurrences of the problem and see if there is a pattern, e.g. if the problem occurs at a certain time of day.

Certainly increasing the timeout is not a bad idea (if it is currently set pretty low) and may resolve the problem in and of itself.

Comment: thanks for the suggestions can It be IIS problem (worker proocess)? There is no such pattern, application error log show few errors time to time but none of them break the application.I have a suspicion that worker process get to fill or something similar and restarting webserver solve the issue ?

Comment: you try by restarting sql server service or check any transaction sql queries not committing or not.

Comment: restarting sql server don't solve issue and I can see login details of users are committed to DB (time name and etc) that means  sql queries are committing.

Comment: Thanks adding timeout = 1000 resolved my issue.Also interesting to note here is that I couldn't turn on activity monitor on sql server at the time of error does that mean these is something wrong with the network? How I can I check network issues I need to talk to system admin please guide.